# psycopg2 unicodeencodeerror with german umlauts

Tags: python, python-3.x, psycopg2

I got a problem with my current python script.

I use `os.walk` to scan predefined directories return a list with all image files found. I compare that list with a `postgres` database via `psycopg2`.

It works fine until I reach a subdirectory or a file with a `german umlaut` in its name (`äöü`) then it get the following error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 146-147: surrogates not allowed`

My current code looks as follows:

```
import psycopg2
import settings
import os


def open_conn():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
                            user=settings.DB_USER,
                            password=settings.DB_PW,
                            host=settings.DB_IP,
                            port=settings.DB_Port,
                            database=settings.DB_DB
                        )
    return conn


def filterExtensions(file_, extensions_):
    if file_.lower().endswith(extensions_):
        return True
    return False


def getFiles(path_, topdown_=False):
    files_found = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path_, topdown=topdown_):
        for name in files:
            files_found.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return files_found


for folders_ in settings.FILE_DIR:
    files_found = getFiles(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), folders_))


conn = open_conn()
cur = conn.cursor()


for file_ in files_found:
    qs = "SELECT * FROM image_meta WHERE sourcefile = '" + file_ + "';"
    cur.execute(qs)
    conn.commit()
```

as soon as I get to `cur.execute(qs)` I get the error.

when I hardcoded the path only for testing it works flawlessly.

```
qs = "SELECT * FROM image_meta WHERE sourcefile = '/src/filecrawler/filecrawler/images/original/Grüner_Testordner/IMG_0004.CR2';"
```

I'm running on `python3` and `psycopg2 2.8.3`

EDIT:
After changing my code as holdenweb and frankegoesdown pointed out I still get the same error.

```
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    cur.execute(qs, (file_,))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 101-102: surrogates not allowed
```

I dont know if its important but the files and folders are created on a mac.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'm afraid your method of constructing your query
is never recommended.

Python database modules allow you to use [*parameterized queries*](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters), which contain
placeholders for actual data values. The values themselves are then provided in
a tuple passed as the second argument to the cursor's `execute` method.

`psycopg2` uses the *pyformat* parameterization mechanism, so try replacing
the problematic statements with

```
qs = "SELECT * FROM image_meta WHERE sourcefile = %s"
cur.execute(qs, (file_,))
```

This will ensure your SQL is correctly constructed. If you still get problems they may be related to an incorrect encoding assumption about filenames.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code accordingly but I still get the same error. I edited my Question.

Comment: But the error report changed - why? Don't assume you've found the cause of the problem until you understand fully what's going on. It might also be a good idea to add print calls until you find out what's going on. Investigate actively, don't just sit around waiting for answers!

Comment: Well its nice how fast people jump to conclusions. The error is still at the position of the ä the position changed because im giving the cur.execute an argument and not a preconstructed string. As soon as I change the ä within the foldername it works. I already tried print statements within my code and everything works just fine. It prints out the path including the ä without any issue. But as soon as it hits the ```cur.execute``` it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll leave this to more capable (and patient) answerers.

Comment: thank you anyway for your initial answer. I changed my queries accordingly

Answer (score 3):

```
for file_ in files_found:
    qs = "SELECT * FROM image_meta WHERE sourcefile = %s;"
    cur.execute(qs, (file_, ))
    conn.commit()
```

as @holdenweb says everything you can see in this article: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code accordingly but I still get the same error. I edited my Question.